# Cannot eval Clojure buffer in inferior REPL

Tags: emacs, clojure

I'm trying to work with Clojure using `inferior lisp mode`. My setup:

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "lein repl")
(run-lisp) ;; Clojure REPL appears then...
```

When I evaluate short forms using `lisp-eval-region`, there are not any errors. But, when I try to eval a long region or even entire buffer, I face the following strange behavior:

1. The input text sent to the REPL buffer is full of rubbish symbols: 
   `(doseq [addr addresses][53G[38G[54G`
2. For unknown reason, some symbols are cut and so cannot be found:
   `(u/validat (:entity_id obj)[61G[46G[62G` Whereas in the code I have `(u/validate-access!`.

More comprehensive dump [is here](https://gist.github.com/igrishaev/42d182235c5b28043e494c62255bdf66).

ps: I've been working with cider for a long time, just wondering are there any alternatives.

Comment: I don't think clojure repl is compatible with it. Why not use cider?

Comment: inferior lisp mode is compatible with any REPL since it operates on its STDIN.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "rubbish symbols" are [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#CSI_codes) for putting the cursor on a certain column. Your REPL process is outputting these, and Emacs's process buffer doesn't know how to handle them.

Notice that in a `lein repl` when you type a closing parenthesis your cursor will briefly jump back to the opening one, that's what those escape codes do.

You're right that `inf-lisp` should work, Rich Hickey used it for a long time, maybe he still does. I would try using it with the plain built-in Clojure REPL, instead of with Leiningen's, since the latter really expects an actual terminal on the other end.

```
(setq inferior-lisp-program "lein run -m clojure.main")
```

Also consider using [inf-clojure](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/inf-clojure), it's very similar to inf-lisp, but is better suited for use with Clojure.

Comment: Thank you, will try native REPL then.

Comment: I have tested it today, native Clojure REPL really woks, thanks again!